# How do I position a document in the lower left corner using Adobe InDesign CS4 Scripting?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs4

I am a complete newbie to this scripting language.  I need take a document and prior to outputting the single page document to a postscript file I need to place it in the lower left corner of the page.  I have looked into the properties of "printPreferences" and have come up with nothing (why PagePositions doesn't support anything besides only variations of CENTERED I don't know).

I have tried to do a quick manipulation of

```
marginPreferences.top = marginPreferences.top + marginPrefernces.bottom;
bottom = 0;
```

Pretty lazy I know.  Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm relatively new to scripting too but mostly you can only do what the application normally supports.

Your choices seem to be (from http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs4js/pc_PrintPreference.html)

```
PagePositions.UPPER_LEFT
PagePositions.CENTER_HORIZONTALLY
PagePositions.CENTER_VERTICALLY
PagePositions.CENTERED
```

Anyway, to do what I think you are trying to do, you could make a script to output your file to a pdf, then create a new document and place that pdf exactly where you want on the page (make the page the same size as your printer paper), and then output that file to your postscript file.